# Monotouch - Populate a UIViewPicker

Tags: xamarin.ios, uipickerview

Is there a quick way to populate a UIPickerView with values?

I have the picker in a XIB all by itself, and when the view is displayed, I would like to have the UIPickerView populated.

Would someone please enlighten me!!

thanks
tony

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to create a class derived from UIPickerViewModel, supplying implementations for GetComponentCount/GetRowsInComponent/GetTitle.

Then, in the controller associated with your nib, assign the "Model" property of your picker to an instance of your UIPickerViewModel derivation.

Comment: Just answered it....   we are bailing on the monotouch stuff.   Too many issues - sorry novell.